# difference between different types of stack declaration

Tags: java

I am new to java and wanted to know difference between

```
Stack<Integer>st=new Stack<Integer>();
```

and

```
Stack<Integer>st=new Stack<>();
```

I know polymorphism but don't exactly know how above statements are different.

Comment: They're equivalent

Comment: Perhaps you should look at it :https://www.javaworld.com/article/2074080/core-java/core-java-jdk-7-the-diamond-operator.html

Comment: traditional syntax and diamond syntax

Comment: And why did you ask the same question twice? And, for the future: you are expected to do serious research prior posting questions. Rest assured: when you are a newbie, anything you can dream of asking has been asked and answered here. And most likely, you can find zillions of books or tutorials explaining these things, too.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Java Tutorials generics lesson](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html#diamond):

> In Java SE 7 and later, you can replace the type arguments required to invoke the constructor of a generic class with an empty set of type arguments (`<>`) as long as the compiler can determine, or infer, the type arguments from the context. This pair of angle brackets, `<>`, is informally called the diamond. For example, you can create an instance of Box with the following statement:
>
> `Box<Integer> integerBox = new Box<>();`

Answer (score 0):

> This is the same. Starting from Java 7 those types in declaration are
>   redundant as they are inferred automatically :
>   **[type-inference-generic-instance-creation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html)**

```
For example, consider the following variable declaration:

Map<String, List<String>> myMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

In Java SE 7, you can substitute the parameterized type of the constructor with an empty set of type parameters (<>):

```
Map<String, List<String>> myMap = new HashMap<>();
```

But you still can use both for Java 7+

Comment: But you obviously use the <> operator for Java 7+ unless you have good reasons to not do that.